# how to populate empty select in angular 9

Tags: angular

I try to populate my dropdownlist with data from .net web api.
I don't have any eror and its appear that some data is her but I can't bind it.
any idea??

my code

employee.component.html

```
<div class="form-group">  
      <label>Select your Department</label>
    <select class="custom-select" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.formData.Departments" 
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >
      <option value="" disabled>
        Choose your department
      </option>
      <option *ngFor="let dept of departments" [ngValue]="dept.DepartmentId">
        {{ dept.dname }}
      </option>
    </select> 
  </div>
```

employee.component.ts

```
public departments: Array<Department>; 

this.loadDepartments();

    loadDepartments() {        
        return this.departmentService.getDepartments().subscribe(departments => this.departments = departments);    
      }
```

Department.Service.ts

```
getDepartments(): Observable<Department[]> {
    return this.http.get<Department[]>(this.url + '/alldepartmentdetails');
  }
```

[dropdownlist emty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLXZo.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Remove this line `<option value="" disabled>
        Choose your department
      </option> ` and change ngValue to   `<option *ngFor="let dept of departments" [ngValue]="dept">
        {{ dept.dname }}
      </option>`

Answer (score 1):

It's work now

```
    div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 20px;">  
    <label>Select your Department </label>
    <select [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.formData.DepartmentId" (change)="selectChangeHandler($event)" class="form-control" required>
      <option value="Choose your department" disabled>
        Choose your department
      </option>
      <option *ngFor="let dept of departments" value= "{{dept.DepartmentId}}" >
        {{ dept.DName }}
    </select> 
  </div>



enter code here
```

Comment: I think there might be a missing `</option>` as the third-to-last line.